# replaceAll - не удаляется подстрока

Tags: java, android

Нужно из строки `"Привет, как дела? (site.ru)"` удалить подстроку `(site.ru)`.

Делаю так, но скобки остаются:

```
String strRep = "(site.ru)";
str = str.replaceAll(strRep, "");
```

Как удалить подстроку со скобками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `replace` вместо `replaceAll`:

```
String strRep = "(site.ru)";
str = str.replace(strRep, "");
```

Метод `replace` принимает в качестве аргумента простую строку (`replaceAll` регулярное выражение). Таким образом отпадает необходимость экранировать скобки.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш способ лучше подошел

Answer (score 2):

Метод `replaceAll()` первым параметром принимает регулярное выражение

```
   @param   regex
 *          the regular expression to which this string is to be matched
 * @param   replacement
 *          the string to be substituted for each match
```

---

Скобки являются метасимволом в регулярных выражениях и должны быть экранированы.

```
String strRep = "\\(site.ru\\)";
str = str.replaceAll(strRep, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод `replaceAll(...)` имеет следующую сигнатуру:

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

Как видно из вышенаписанного, первым параметром является **регулярное выражение** согласно которому будет производится замена, а не **строка**, которая будет заменена.

Круглые скобки в регулярных выражениях имеют определенный смысл (группировка). Для того, чтобы скобки воспринимались как часть текста, их необходимо экранировать. Соответственно, рабочий вариант будет выглядеть так:

```
String str = "Привет, как дела? (site.ru)";
String strRep = "\\(site.ru\\)";
str = str.replaceAll(strRep, "");
```

Если Вам требуется **просто заменить одну строку на другую** (без использования регулярных выражений), то целесообразно использовать метод `replace(...)`:

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

Тогда код будет выглядеть так:

```
String str = "Привет, как дела? (site.ru)";
String strRep = "(site.ru)";
str = str.replace(strRep, "");
```